# ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-uvm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel. This may be because it is in use

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

when I tried to install nvidia driver. I got this problem.
*ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-uvm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X

         server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module

         unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based

         programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured 
         that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.*

I tried reboot,and close Xserver, which didn't work. 
and when I tried "sudo modprobe -r nvidia_uvm", it said "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/modules.dep.bin'"

it's bothered me for a few weeks.
please please help me.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   4.15.0-42 is a rather old (Nov 2018) kernel ; and 4.15 is used by multiple OSes, but either way I'd suggest upgrading your system (`dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade`)

Comment: I am not sure. How should I upgrade my system? what's the command? does that work?
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` will update your software lists (what packages are available using your current sources, which is followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade any packages; a `sudo apt-get upgrade` will upgrade some but with restrictions; the 'dist-upgrade' does all upgrade does plus ... (see `man apt-get` for details; search (/) for dist-upgrade).  Your system is over a year behind in at least some packages given your kernel

Comment: I already did it. but it never worked. what can I do? I can't unload nvidia-uvm.